# heartbeat turn on a third network card

Tags: linux, heartbeat

I am trying to read the configuration of haresources of heartbeat to see how can I make this possible.
I have an IP given by my ISP and my servers are running heartbeat.  So I want to turn on a network card once it becomes primary server. 
This ip is something like 74.1.1.2 with a gw like 74.1.1.1, I cant have a other ips like 74.1.1.3 and 74.1.1.4, it might conflict with the isp.

I think I can maybe have something like 192.168.201.1 set on this card and add virtual interface with 74.1.1.2.  It doesnt seem ideal.
Can I add a default gw on haresources too?

What would be the best approach to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get heartbeat to do anything you want -- managing resources is done entirely by calling external programs, so if the existing resource agents don't do the job (I'm not sure that any built-in RA will activate a NIC, but I've never looked for that specific functionality) you want to write a shell script that does exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I am looking for an example to do this, I am reading the docs, do you know of a simple script i can just add ifup eth1 and ifdown eth1 if down.